# How to display a message box before starting Inno Setup installer

Tags: inno-setup, istool

I want to add a `MsgBox` before installation, right after the `setup.exe` runs.

Like this:

[image]

and after [*OK*] continues to installation procedure.

I'm using **ISTool**.